# Microsoft Graph API: set general channel settings

Tags: microsoft-graph-api, microsoft-teams, microsoft-graph-teams

Seems like there isn't a way to set primary channel settings using Graph API

[image]

I need to set Primary Channel `ModerationSettngs.UserNewMessageRestriction = UserNewMessageRestriction.Moderators` but:

- If I add this setting to the Team creation (`await graphClient.Teams.Request().AddAsync(team)`) it's ignored
- If i try to change this settings after I created the Team using `await graphClient.Teams[myTeamId].Channels[myChannelId].Request().UpdateAsync(channel)` I get an error that tell me that "Primary channel cannot be patched"

I'm using Microsoft Graph API beta version

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Currently there no API to edit the settings of a primary channel. When you create a team the primary channel will be automatically created. If you want to set settings you can create a new channel and you can add settings to that using .

Comment: From Microsoft Team application it's possibile to edit some settings of the general channel. Why this should not be possibile via API?

Comment: I have edited my answer. Could you please check.